# I don't know how to fix problem with events?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, event-listener

I am building a battleship game in js. I added event listener on targeted element of the grid and I am trying to make a function that takes one argument (boat length) and according to that argument, function should render the boat on my grid. Problem is that no matter what argument I passed in to the function it renders the boat same length. I think that problem is event listener that stays the same when I clicked the element first time.

Here is the code:

```
function placeBoat (boatLength){
    domElements.yourGrid.onclick = function(event){
        let target = event.target;
        console.log(event)
        let clickedPosition = target.id
        let clickedPositionId = clickedPosition.slice(4, 6)
        let clikedPositionInt = parseInt(clickedPositionId);
        for(let i = 0; i < boatLength; i++){
            target.style.background = "green";
            target = document.querySelector("#cell" + clikedPositionInt)
            clikedPositionInt += 10;
        }
    }
}

domElements.boat1Button.addEventListener("click", placeBoat(3))
domElements.boat2Button.addEventListener("click", placeBoat(4))
domElements.boat3Button.addEventListener("click", placeBoat(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

addEventListener's second argument is the listener function ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener ). However, you're calling the function `placeBoat` instead of passing a function as an argument.

Let's start with a simple explanation. Define some new functions without arguments and add event listeners using them:

```
function placeBoat3() {
    placeBoat(3);
}
function placeBoat4() {
    placeBoat(4);
}
function placeBoat5() {
    placeBoat(5);
}

domElements.boat1Button.addEventListener("click", placeBoat3)
domElements.boat2Button.addEventListener("click", placeBoat4)
domElements.boat3Button.addEventListener("click", placeBoat5)
```

As you can see, now second arguments to addEventListener are function names without parenthesis. Once you are comfortable with that idea, you can move forward and use arrow functions. Get rid of the new functions and call addEventListeners like below:

```
domElements.boat1Button.addEventListener("click", () => placeBoat(3))
domElements.boat2Button.addEventListener("click", () => placeBoat(4))
domElements.boat3Button.addEventListener("click", () => placeBoat(5))
```

`() => placeBoat(3)` is a shorthand to define a function with no arguments and which calls `placeBoat(3)` in its body. You can learn more about them at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions